# How to create a buffer around a point that takes terrain elevation in account?

Tags: qgis, distance, buffer, elevation, population

In QGIS, I am creating a few different buffer around points to simulate walking distances. For example, 10 minutes walk about 800m at 5km/h. Using population density, I then clip a population layer which gives me the population that is within a 10 min walk from those points.
I am working on a hilly city where elevation does matter.

How can I adjust the buffer with elevation?

Comment: QGIS does not do 3D geoprocessing.  One thing you may have to do, is to do the calculations in the attribute table of the input feature (ie: point location to be buffered).  Then with the calculated value in the attribute table you could buffer on that value.  It would still be 2D, but it would provide a more realistic distance in the hilly locations.

Comment: The QGIS plugins page isn't loading but I have to believe there is one that can handle cost based distance.  You can use your elevation data to create a cost raster and do a cost distance buffer to calculate all locations within a 10 min walk from that location.  http://pgrouting.org/ looks promising as far as plugins go.

Comment: The suggestion by @James is a good one, with a modification: a "costdistance" calculation won't work, because the time to walk across a grid cell depends on the orientation of the walk (it's much easier to go downhill or sidegradient than uphill!).  Calculations that take path orientation into account are sometimes called "pathdistance" calculations: that is what you're looking for.