# 3D buffers according to landscape surface in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, buffer, 3d

Using ArcGIS (10.3.1), is it possible to create a buffer zone according to the surface with a variable radius (i.e. 5-10-15 Km)?

With surface/terrain I mean the landscape, so the buffer would be adapted on the true landscape surface. Therefore, the buffer zone should display the reachable distance (within the chosen radius) according to the cost surface.

[image]

I tried using the buffer wizard, but the result achieved is "flat", which means that it does not respect the surface changes.

---

@User2009  With surface/terrain I mean the landscape, so the buffer would be adapted on the true landscape surface. Therefore, the buffer zone should display the reachable distance (within the chosen radius) according to the cost surface.
sorry, I hope having been more clear now.

[image: in red the usual buffer zone; in blue the buffer adapted on the surface]

Comment: ok, thanks...But will the buffer respect the surface? Which means,will the circle be "irregular" because adapted to the terrain trend? (just to make clear)

Comment: I know how to make a buffer zone, but I miss how to create a buffer zone according to the surface

Comment: Sorry But I didn't understand what do you mean by surface (terrain)? You stated that you want to have the buffer at (5,10,15,..km).can you add a screenshot of what your result should be?

Comment: I think it is possible to do with allocation path. Try with this> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252096/generating-fixed-distance-buffer-including-slope-using-arcgis-desktop