# How to create a sloped buffer in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I need to create a simple 4,000 ft buffer around a single polygon. The buffer needs to slope upwards at a slope of 20:1, essentially creating a "bowl" floating above the terrain with a flat bottom and raised sides (see pictures below). It does not need to follow terrain, simply change from one constant elevation at its inner edge to a new constant elevation at it's outer edge. I've tried using the Euclidean Distance tool to calculate distance and then the slope/elevation, but the tool failed with Error 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Is there any way to generate this from the elevation setting or during the creation of the buffer?

[image: Top view of what I'm looking for. The inner oval is the original polygon, the outer orange oval is the buffer.]
[image: Side view. The bottom of the trapezoid is the original polygon, and the orange is the sloping buffer. The terrain is shown below the floating map feature.]

Comment: What do you mean by slope upwards? Edit your question and include some images. To say a tool just failed is not helpful, what was the error message?

Comment: If you want your buffer to reflect 3d/terrain distances there is a stack exchange discussion (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252096/generating-fixed-distance-buffer-including-slope-using-arcgis-desktop) and an ESRI Forum thread: https://community.esri.com/t5/mapping-questions/is-it-possible-to-take-pre-existing-buffers-make/td-p/704844/page/2.  A path distance with dem approach was suggested in the threads.